# active directory group.members.contains crashes on "Users" with unknown error

Tags: c#, active-directory

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var groupNames = args;

    var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

    var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, Environment.UserName);

    var groupPrincipals = new List<GroupPrincipal>();

    groupPrincipals.AddRange(groupNames.Select(name => GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, IdentityType.Name, name)));
    groupPrincipals = groupPrincipals.Where(gp => gp != null).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine(groupPrincipals.Any(gp => gp.Members.Contains(user)));

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

When I'm trying to run this code it crashes on

```
Console.WriteLine(groupPrincipals.Any(gp => gp.Members.Contains(user)));
```

With Exception :

```
PrincipalOperationException
Unknown error (0x80005000)
```

I'm trying to determine whether I'm a member of group "Users".Debug view shows me that "Users" contains 3 items, but membership check crashes

Comment: Please try if you can print out all the items in `gp.Members`.  I suspect you may be able to print some of them and crash at one of the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found out that it's a Access denied error code. After rewriting this code (getting user's groups and then check whether they contain specified group) it works